# WHat is the use the Git Info in YAML Azure container files

Tags: azure-container-instances

We are actually evaluation the deployment of docker image to Azure container instance. For that we are using YAML file as defined in the following link
[Yaml file srtucture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-reference-yaml)

In that structure I have notice a section relative to Git repository

What is the use of the entry and in which case scenario we use it ?

Thanks for help
Regards

Comment: Block sequences in collections indicate each entry with a dash and space (-) and each entry begins with a new line

Comment: You did not answer my question, I know that. My question was that in the structure there is a section dedicated to Git repo and I am asing what is the use of it and in which scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Docker Images is maintain in `Git Repro`.

Example : If you will go Docker Hub and search for any images using `docker pull imagesName` you can directly install the latest images.

In backend Devlopers work on `Existing Images` and once they update anything on exisiting Image they push it to github with new version.

So Same here in this YAML file we are using Git Repro so any new version of code(images) update by `developer or you`. Then by continuoues deployment the exisning container wil update with latest images.

For Reference you can take this ***[docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx)*** and in down of this link there is link for **[Where to file issues](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx)** in code section you able to see the code of this image.